# How to play one video after another with Media Source Extensions API?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video, media-source

I have two (or more) mp4 videos.
I want to play them one after another in the HTML `<video>` tag and avoid any delay or flickering.

Currently I use multiple `<video>` tags and swap them when needed.

I was hoping to do that with the Media Source Extensions API.
How can this be done?

Comment: Convert the video fragmented mp4 and just feed the buffer with the two videos inserting the initialization fragment before the second one.

Comment: @szatmary I am unable to get the videos converted to fmp4 if that's what you mean.

Comment: Then your question is a contradiction. Because standard mp4s can not be played with media source extensions.